# If $\vec u$ is orthogonal to both $\vec v $ and $\vec w$, and $\vec u$ not equal to $0$, prove $\vec u$ is not in the span of $ \vec v$ and $\vec w$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**QN: If *u* is orthogonal to both *v* and *w*, and u ≠ 0, argue that *u* is not in the span of *v* and *w*.**

Where I am at:
[image]

I get stuck when it comes to solving my augmented matrix with Gauss Jordan Elimination.

I also tried formulating the following steps to solve the problem.

1. Create instances of *u*, *v* and w that pertain to the question. My visualisation in Geogebra can be viewed here: https://ggbm.at/b6xvwhpa
2. Set u = a*v + b*w = u (where *a* and *b* are constants)
3. Disprove (2)

However, I could not get past step 1.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\def\myvec#1{{\bf#1}}$
This is the same as saying

> if $\myvec u$ is orthogonal to both $\myvec v$ and $\myvec w$, and $\myvec u$ is in the span of $\myvec v$ and $\myvec w$, then $\myvec u=\myvec 0$.

So, if $\myvec u$ is in the span of $\myvec v$ and $\myvec w$, then $\myvec u=a\myvec v+b\myvec w$ for some scalars $a,b$.  Assuming also $\myvec u$ is orthogonal to both $\myvec v$ and $\myvec w$, this means $\myvec u\cdot \myvec v=0$ and $\myvec u\cdot\myvec  w=0$, so
$$\myvec u\cdot \myvec u=\myvec u\cdot(a\myvec v+b\myvec w)=a(\myvec u\cdot \myvec v)+b(\myvec u\cdot \myvec w)=a0+b0=0\ .$$
Since $\myvec u\cdot \myvec u=0$ we have $\myvec u=\myvec 0$.

Comment: I thought about this, however, the question specifically states that *u* can not be zero. If *u* can't be zero does that not prevent the above proof, or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Have you studied proof by contradiction or by contrapositive?  That's what this is.

Answer (score 2):

If $u$ belongs to the span of $v$ and $w$ the $u=av+bw$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$. Since $\langle u, v \rangle=0$ and $\langle u, w \rangle=0$ we get $\langle u, (av+bw) \rangle=0$ so $\langle u, u \rangle=0$. This means $u=0$ which is a contradiction.